# Grid sorting bug when default orderby column type is date. Anyone else with this problem?

Tags: web2py

I have this action

```
@auth.requires(auth.has_membership(CHECKER_ROLE) or auth.has_membership(SUPERVISOR_ROLE))
def list_tags_to_issue():
    """List tags to issue.

    :return: Dict with grid.
    """

   query = ((db.wo.is_active == True)
            & (db.wo.tags_issued == False)
            & (db.wo.pies_verified == False)
            & (db.wo.equipment_id == db.equipment.id))

    grid = SQLFORM.grid(
        query,
        create=False,
        csv=False,
        deletable=False,
        details=False,
        editable=False,
        fields=[db.wo.est_finish,
                db.equipment.name,
                db.wo.sn,
                db.wo.opts,
                db.wo.finished,  # Necessary dummy entry.
                db.wo.canceled_on,  # Necessary dummy entry.
                db.wo.canceled_by,  # Necessary dummy entry.
                db.wo.cancel_approved_by,  # Necessary dummy entry.
        ],
        orderby=db.wo.est_finish,
    )

    return dict(grid=grid)
```

With this view

```
{{extend 'layout.html'}}

<h2>{{=T('List tags to issue')}}</h2>

{{=grid}}

{{if DEV:
=response.toolbar()
pass}}
```

If I try to change the sorting in the default orderby column (est_finish) it doesn't occur.
The URL is changed from ...orderby=do.wo.est_finish to ...orderby=~db.wo.est_finish, but the grid doesn't change.
When I see the db stats, the SQL command also didn't change.
The SQL command is always

```
SELECT "wo"."est_finish", "equipment"."name", "wo"."sn", "wo"."opts", "wo"."finished", "wo"."canceled_on", "wo"."canceled_by", "wo"."cancel_approved_by", "wo"."id" 
FROM "wo", "equipment" 
WHERE (((("wo"."is_active" = 'T') AND ("wo"."tags_issued" = 'F')) AND ("wo"."pies_verified" = 'F')) AND ("wo"."equipment_id" = "equipment"."id")) 
ORDER BY "wo"."est_finish", "wo"."id" LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0;
```

no matter the URL changing from ...orderby=do.wo.est_finish to ...orderby=~db.wo.est_finish.

This is one of 3 different views (all have in common a orderby with a date column) that show this problem. All others work correctly.

If I remove the orderby parameter from the grid or change it to a non-date one, everything works, including the sorting of the date column.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

JM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reporting this issue in the web2py group, it was fixed in version 2.18.5.